# Angular with google map. setTime always run, lead to high CUP and memery leak

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3

My app developed by Angular and google map. But my some action will lead to CPU and memery leak. I follow the code and find the google map code like as follows:
[image]

there are a setTimeout recursion are runing, results of created a lot of zoneTask.
Who can tell me .When And How the `KF` function will be run.Thanks.
any suggestion?

Comment: When I opened the `infowindow` the setTimeout recursion will be run.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828784

As I can see it was accepted by Google, so hopefully one day it will be fixed. Feel free to star and add your comments in the bug report to express your interest and subscribe to updates.

Comment: Thanks your comment. When I updated the map api version to 3.28, the setTimeout loop has been fixed.

Comment: It looks like Google fixed this in 3.28. :)